# How to declare the current value of a variable in Java as final?

Tags: java, final

I am currently writing a program in Java with moving objects that need to have their position at the moment a new object is spawned set as their final position so that they are no longer affected by keyboard commands. I am familiar with declaring instance variables as final, but am looking for a way to lock variables after they are instantiated.

i.e

```
boolean beentype = StdDraw.hasNextKeyTyped();
if (beentype) {
    if (this.y > 1) {
        char key = StdDraw.nextKeyTyped();
        char a1 = 'a';
        char d = 'd';

        if (key == a1 && this.x > 2 && position [i-1][j] == 0) {
            this.x = this.x - movePerCall;
            j = j + 1;
            position[i + 1][j - 1] = 0;
            position[i][j - 1] = 0;
            position[i][j] = 1;

        }

        if (key == d && this.x < 19 && position [i-1][j] == 0) {
            this.x = this.x + movePerCall;
            j = j - 1;
            position[i + 1][j + 1] = 0;
            position[i][j + 1] = 0;
            position[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
```

and once the variable has fulfilled its isDone boolean requirements I would like this.x and this.y to no longer change
thank you

Comment: You _cannot_ make a variable change from non-final to final.  You can initialize a final variable with the value of a non-final variable, though.

Comment: Have you considered moving x and y to another (new) class, make them private and not provide a setter? So you can make them final and set their values in constructor.

Comment: What if you had a field named "finalPosition" and compare the current position against that and not move when you are there?

Comment: Or a boolean variable allowChange=true, set it to false when appropriate. then you check allowChange and change x or y if true, do nothing if it is false.

Comment: *You* are in control of when fields `x` and `y` are updated. The entire *reason* that fields get encapsulated behind getter (and setter) methods is for *you* to control their values. If you don't want the values to change after some point, *you* write the code so it won't happen, e.g. by following suggestion by @FredK.

Comment: So it wouldn't be setting them to final within the boolean it would be only allowing them to be moved while the boolean is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it might make sense to change the design, I don't know for which problem you need this functionality exactly so, as you asked for a lockable integer class:

```
public class LockableInt {

  private int value;
  private boolean locked = false;

  public LockableInt(int initial) {
     value = initial;
  }

  public void setLock(boolean locked) { this.locked = locked; }

  /* Sets the value if not locked, otherwise does nothing.
   */
  public void setValue(int value) {
    if (!locked) { 
      this.value = value; 
    }
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

**So now if you use this class instead of plain `int`:**

instead of `this.x = this.x - movePerCall;` you would do `this.x.setValue(this.x.getValue() - movePerCall);` and if the value should be locked you do `this.x.setLock(true)` after which every subsequent call to `this.x.setValue(...)` will have no effect.

**If its not just variables of type integer that you want to lock in the future:**

You can of course easily generify the class that I posted above and reuse that for any type you use in your application.

Comment: so you might mark this as an answer if you find it perfect :D